# Is there a way to force a global refresh of views when entering the foreground?

Tags: ios, swift

My UI undergoes a complete color change every day at a specific time. To handle this, I created a `UIColor` `extension` and added a `switch` at each color that switches on the client's current local time. Therefore, whenever a color is called by a view, it uses the appropriate color depending on the time of day. Here is an example:

**UIColor extension**

```
// text color
public class var text: UIColor {
    switch currentHour {
    case 0...5, 20...23: // from 8 PM to 5:59 AM
        return UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
    default: // from 6 AM to 7:59 PM
        return UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

In addition to updating `currentHour` in the app delegate when the app launches, it also updates it when the app enters the foreground:

**In the app delegate**

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    // update current hour
    updateCurrentHour()

}
```

The only thing missing is forcefully refreshing an entire view controller when the app enters the foreground so that the views within it are forced to call `UIColor` and get their appropriate colors.

1. How do I force a view controller to "refresh" its entire view? Or is there a way to force a refresh on just the views that call on `UIColor` (since they are the only objects that need a color update)?
2. If the user is deep into a navigation stack, places the app in the background and then enters the foreground, and that view controller (at the top of the stack) is successfully refreshed, what happens when the user pops back down the stack? Were those view controllers refreshed?
3. Or is there a way to force a "global refresh" that doesn't lose the user's position in their stacks?

Comment: Maybe call layoutSubviews

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your view controllers register for this notification: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification.name/1622944-uiapplicationwillenterforeground. When the notification arrives, refresh.

If a view controller refreshes when that notification is received and also gets the colors right in its `viewDidLoad`, you have covered all possible cases. All the view controllers whose views the user ever sees will have the right colors.

You might also want to issue this notification yourself, from some central place (i.e. the app delegate), that is watching the clock, so that you refresh when the moment arrives even if the app is open at that moment.

Comment: It worked beautifully, thank you. And based on the quality of your answers, I'll be purchasing your books. One follow-up: there seems to be a lot of methods to "refreshing/reloading/redrawing" self.view, what is your recommendation?

Comment: @sconewolf I can't give you a one-size-fits-all answer to that. The key is: know what events the Cocoa framework wants to send you, and when they are sent; slot your code where the right thing will happen at the right time.

Comment: I don't know what it would mean to reload a view. If you have to change a property of a view, you just change it. Perhaps it would help you to know about the tint color? It automatically propagates from the window on down right through the interface.